# Access API methods in NON IE browsers

Tags: javascript

i have a device in aspx page  inside a table td tag as below

```
<td style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">
       <object id="Myobject" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" height="0" width="0"                                     classid="CLSID:6283f7ea-608c-11dc" name="Myobject" >
       </object>
</td>
```

The object has many many methods that are accessible in ie 6,7 and 9. It throws an error "Object method not supported" or "Object method not found in Google Chrome/Mozilla

how do i access these methods?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

There is a distact lack of any data associated with that `<object>`. Presumably, however, it is an ActiveX control.

ActiveX controls are not supported by any browser other then Internet Explorer on Windows.

In short, you can't.

Comment: I had Previously Read that a substitute for ActiveX is Silverlight. But on trying it, silverlight cannot reference the APIs dll since it was not developed to target silverlight. The object runs when done in java where the javaapplet is employed. Dont we have an Aspx equivalent ? Thanks

Comment: How About IE 8? it fails like the other non IEs

Comment: IE8 appears to [lock down](http://www.ehow.com/how_6202033_enable-activex-internet-explorer-8.html) ActiveX controls.

Comment: You're dealing with client side technologies. ASP.NET doesn't get involved.

Comment: "i have a device in aspx page inside a table td tag as below " was my opening statement meaning i am giving you at least full details. It does not necessarily mean that am working from the client side., infact for your information It has back-server side code thats working well and in addition the Technology in place is ASP.NET.